# Set timeout for a specific method invoked by Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this route in my Spring Boot API, which is supposed to receive a Registry object, try save it to the DB and inform whether it was successful or not. This is my controller's method:

```
@POST
@Path( "/save" )
public Response save( @RequestBody Registry registry ) {

    Response validatedResponse = validateRegistry( registry );

    if ( isErrorResponse( validatedResponse ) )
        return validatedResponse;

    try {
        return ResponseBuilder.success( this.registryRepository.save( registry ) );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        LOGGER.error( "Error while trying to save", e );
        return ResponseBuilder.failure( "error at /save" );
    }
}
```

The `validateRegistry` is as follows:

```
private Response validateRegistry( Registry registry ) {

    // some trivial validation on the Registry object's fields        
    
    Optional< Connection > connection;

    try {
        connection = connectionService.findById( registry.getConnectionIdentifier() );
        registryService.setConnection( connection.get() );
        try {
            return registryService.doesRegistryExists( registry );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            LOGGER.failure( "error at /save (validation)" );
            LOGGER.failure( e.getMessage() );
        }
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        return ResponseBuilder.failure( "not able to retrieve connection for given registry ");
    }
    
        return ResponseBuilder.success();
}
```

Part of the validation consists in verifying the existence of an identical registry, so as you can see, I retrieve a connection from the caller in order to access its base and search for the registry - that's what `registryService.doesRegistryExists` does. Now, I want to limit the execution of `doesRegistryExists` to a few seconds, since sometimes it takes too much time to execute the query - it's ok to abort the execution, since I can just return a Response describing the situation and asking to try again later.

What should I do? I've tried using ExecutorService to wrap the query caller, but it causes the caller to throw NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: If you have a timeout with connection and probably the DB, it would make sense the connection itself to have a timeout set in there instead of wrapping it in another project. Also because you are using spring-boot you can use the annotation of @Transactional(timeout = 5) to have a timeout of 5 seconds as well

Comment: Makes sense, but unfortunately I can't change the Connection class

Comment: Just tried the @Transactional(timeout = 5) annotation, but aparently nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Using an `ExecutorService` is a good solution, you can get a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) by submitting a [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and wait for the result until a certain amount of time

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

private Response validateRegistry( Registry registry ) {
  ...
  try {
    Callable<Response> task = () -> registryService.doesRegistryExists(registry);
    Future<Response> future = executorService.submit(task);
    // wait for the result for at most 2 seconds
    return future.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  } catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // handle the timeout exception here
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // handle the other exceptions here        
  }
  ... 
}
```

Comment: When either the query executor or its caller executes inside a Callable, it throws a NullPointerException

Comment: What is the cause of the `NullPointerException` ?

Comment: It just says "java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException", without the stack trace